How to set the maximum response size for feign client call?
I am using feign client to call an api in a spring boot application. It is failing because of the huge size of the response. Approx 10MB. Tried to setup in application.yml
feign:client:config:default:maxResponseSize: 10485760 but it's not working.
Could not find any proper reference of the maxResponseSize.
Appreciate any help towards the resolution.
